# Story identification : About children getting butterfly wings because of a tree

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I remember reading a book (published by Scholastic at that time) with a large tree on its cover and the following story line. But can't remember the name !

Story line (Spoiler alert !) :

There was a small place where a boy and girl go on an adventure to find a tree that has these sparkly particles that are butterfly wings' remains. Also they eat the fruit of the tree. After some days, one of them undergoes metamorphosis like a caterpillar to butterfly and gets wings. Soon they discover other kids from the town are also getting wings, but were secretly operated upon by their adults who always knew of the secret.

Anyone got any idea bout the name of the book ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[The Things With Wings](http://www.gregoryholch.com/_b_the_things_with_wings__b__93696.htm)* by Greg Holch

From Amazon:

> Every year the Emerald Rainbow butterflies return to Angel Falls, and children disappear. Newton and Vanessa want to know why. When they discover the secret -- that they can become butterflies -- they face an awesome decision.

None of the covers I've found depict a tree, but the other details match up. The tree provides the transformation. Children are transforming and being disappeared by a mysterious figures in a black hat.

Comment: That story was stolen by another one called "Wings" which that Athure totally stole from the AMAZING original story, "The Things with Wings" and that's exactly why every time I try to find the original one the "Wings" pop up instead and now that's a "popular" book now